# How to use \star or _\epsilon inside in a command like a command \tag{}?

Tags: equations, symbols, texstudio

Im use texstudio and i trying use \tag in the command \begin{equation}, the following form

> \begin{equation}\tag{P1_\epsilon}
>
> ... 1+1=2 ...
>
> \end{equation}

But, texstudop compiles with errors.Is there any way to do this using another command?

Comment: The argument to `\tag` is typeset in text mode, so you want `\tag{P$1_\epsilon$}`

Comment: @egreg Oh man! you are my hero. I trying \tag{P1$_\epsilon$} and this and it went wrong... But \tag{P$1_\epsilon$} it worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\tag{}` command exits mathmode so you have to surround your argument with `$ $`.  Also, you can not have empty lines inside `\begin{equation}  \end{equation}`.  You can either eliminate them or add a `%` if you want.  I recommend indenting the contents of the equation to visually separate it.

```
\begin{equation}\tag{$P1_\epsilon$}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{$P1_\epsilon$}
%
1 + 1 = 2
%
\end{equation}
```